# Google Firebase uid web

Tags: javascript, firebase, datatables

I'm trying to get the google ID (using the function getGoogleID()) to build a variable that has a URL parameter, it gets sent to PHP. I have tried it with hardcoding the correct string in, but can't get it so it's unique to the logged in user. Its being used with DataTables.

```
//Code to call Google to get uid
function getGoogleID() {
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
    return user.uid;
    };
};

//Code to Build Datatable
function buildTable(uid) {

        $('#assessmentTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "paging":false,
            "ajax": "connect/fm/customerAssessmentsList.php?id=" + uid,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "fieldData.Remote Tests::Test Date"},
                {"data": "fieldData.Remote Test Calculations::Test Name"},
                {"data": "fieldData.Result 1"},
                {"data": "fieldData.Result 2"},
                {"data": "fieldData.Result 3"},
                {"data": "fieldData.Result 4"}
            ],
            order: [[1, 'asc'],[0,'desc']],
            rowGroup: {
                dataSrc: 'fieldData.Remote Test Calculations::Test Name',
                className: 'bg-success text-white'
            },
            "responsive":true
        });
    }
//Document Ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uid = getGoogleID();
    buildTable(uid);
});
```

What am I missing? I can call getGoogleID() in the console and get a proper response. It's almost like it calls the buildTable() before getGoogleID() finishes and returns the uid.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug in a browser and see what it is calling first. Anyway, you can use a if or call the uid in the function buldTable directly. It can also be a scope problem.

//Document Ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getGoogleID() {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        if (user != null) {
           return user.uid;
        };
     };
    var uid = getGoogleID();

    //define buildTable here

    //Then call it
    buildTable(uid);
    if (uid !=  null || typeof(uid) != 'undefined' || uid != ""){
       buildTable(uid);
     } else {
      //do something
     }

});
```

Comment: It didn't work. What do you mean by scope? I'm also wondering if it's a variable type problem.

Comment: A scope poblem here would be when the document is created, the two functions getGoogleID() and buildTable() do not exist. Can you try to move these functions like in my edits.